# How to find the closest div by ID and then find the ID's of all forms inside that div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to to find the closest div with an class of 'form_wrap' to the button when clicked and then find the ID's of all forms inside that div.

The forms sit as part of two Laravel foreach loops and have been given individual dynamic ID numbers. These ID numbers need to be collected and then submitted.

```
<div class="form_wrap">  
    @foreach ($workouts as $workout)
         <?php $formid="form_".$x."_".$f;?>
         {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'workoutshared.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'ID' => $formid)) !!}
         {{ csrf_field() }}
         {{ Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id)}}
         {{ Form::hidden('date', $entry)}}
         {{ Form::hidden('weight', $workout->weight)}}
         {{ Form::hidden('exercise', $workout->exercise)}}
         {{ Form::hidden('reps', $workout->reps)}}
         {{ Form::hidden('sets', $workout->sets)}}
         <button id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Share</button>               
         {{ Form::checkbox('share', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => ''))}}
         {!! Form::close() !!}     
         <tr>
               <th>{{$workout->exercise}}</th>
               <td>{{$workout->weight}}</td>
               <td>{{$workout->reps}}</td>
               <td>{{$workout->sets}}</td>
         </tr>
    <?php $f++; endforeach;?>
 </div>
```

Comment: There is no closest by ID, ID's are unique, so there is **only one** element with any given ID.

Comment: closest div to what? What is the start point?

Comment: Me being lazy. Have edited to be classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many details you've left out, so the answers may need to be modified to match.

For example - do you want to allow the form submission? Intercept it? Or do you care?

Another point is - what do you want to do with the ID's once you have them?

This code will do what you've asked.  It uses event delegation, so you should be able to load it in your `<head>`, and it will still work as requested.

```
// Bind to the click event of all form buttons
$(document).on('click', 'form button', function() {
    // Find the closest div
    var wrap = $(this).closest('div.form_wrap');

    // Then, find all form ID's inside of the div:
    wrap.find('form').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).prop('id');
    });
});
```

What you do with those ID's is up to you, but there's several options, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, all works perfectly pulling the correct form ID's to the console. I would then like to submit the forms as part of the same process. I gather through AJAX or is there a simpler process? @cale_b

Comment: Which forms?  All of them? You can't submit multiple forms together, so you'd have to intercept the form submission of the one that was clicked, and then do some javascript work to combine the form info (either through dom manipulation, or you could use AJAX).  But that is a separate question.  This answers the question you've asked, if you need further help in accomplishing your *new* scope, then you should post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `$( "[id^='form_']" )` which finds any ID that starts with "form_" although using a class is a better option when trying to find more than one element on a page.

```
var formWrap = $( "#SomeSpecificID" ).parent();
var formsInsideThatID = formWrap.children().attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks @darham. I am looking to find the closest class to that instance on the jQuery being run, in this case .form_wrap. This jQuery will be looped down the page for each day of the week and will need to find .form_wrap for each day.

Comment: The script will sit just before `<?php $f++; endforeach;?>`

Comment: still not positive exactly what you need but the answer is edited